How to prove a sequence does not converge almost surely

Given a sequence of independent random variables $(X_n)$ with distribution $$P(X_n = 2^n) = \frac{1}{n}, \quad P(X_n = 0) = 1 -
\frac{1}{n}.$$Consider the sequence:$$Y_n = \frac{1}{n}(X_1 + X_2 +
\dots + X_n).$$ Does the sequence $Y_n$ converge almost surely? Why?

I tried to apply the strong law of large numbers but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\operatorname{Var} X_n}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{4^n(n-1)}{n^4}=\infty$, which violates the condition of this theorem. So, it makes me believe that $Y_n$ does not converge almost surely. But how can I actually prove that? Could someone help me? Thanks in advance!

@SigmaAlgebra could you write your solution in the answering section down below so that I can understand better? If yes, I would be very grateful

If you just want to say that $P(Y_n ,,\text {converges})\neq 1$ then the best answer so far is by SamedyMaj. The answer by van der Wolf shows that $Y_n \to \infty$ with probability $1$ which is stronger than  what is asked.

The strong law applies only to i.i.d. sequence of random variables, which is not in your case. If you denote $A_n=\{X_n=2^n\}$ then $A_n$ are independent and $\sum_n \mathbb{P}(A_n)=\infty$, so by the second Borel-Cantelli lemma, events $A_n$ occur infinitely often, and for those $n$ we have $Y_n\ge 2^n/n$, so $Y_n$ cannot converge  to a finite value.
Let $m_{k}=k^{2k}=e^{2 k\ln k}$, and
$$
B_k=\{X_n=0 \text{ for all }n\in[m_k,m_{k+1})\},\ k=1,2,\dots
$$
Then
$$
\mathbb{P}(B_k) \approx \frac{m_k}{m_{k+1}}\approx \frac 1{e^2 k^2}
$$
which is summable over $k$. Therefore, by the Borel-Cantelli lemma, only finitely many $B_k$ will occur. However, on $B_k^c$ for $n\in [m_k,m_{k+1})$ we have $X_n=2^n\ge 2^{m_k}$ for some $n$ in this interval, and hence for all $n\in [m_{k+1},m_{k+2})$,
$$
Y_n\ge \frac1{m_{k+2}} 2^{m_k}=e^{k^{2k}(\ln 2+o(1))}
$$
Thus $Y_n\to\infty$ a.s.

An interesting case also arises if we take $P(X_{n}=n)=\frac{1}{n}$ and $P(X_{n}=0)=1-\frac{1}{n}$. I don't really know how to show almost sure convergence in this case to $1$ without using some Martingale theory.

@Mr.GandalfSauron Can you please clarify how to show that $\liminf Y_n$ is not finite differently? A priori, it's conceivable that e.g. $\liminf Y_n=0$ whilst $\limsup Y_n=\infty$. Thanks!

@Wolf In which one? Do you mean in the case I suggested of $n\delta_{\frac{1}{n}}+(1-\frac{1}{n})\delta_{0}$? Or do you mean in the original problem?

@Wolf. I see, I wrote $\lim\inf$ instead of $\lim\sup$. What I wanted to say was that I don't see how that's important in showing that $Y_{n}$'s do not converge almost surely.

@Mr.GandalfSauron: I just wanted to show that $Y_n\to\infty$ a.s. This is a  stronger statement that $Y_n$ does not converge to a finite variable. If we allow convergence to infinity, then the answer to the question "Does $Y_n$ converge a.s.?" would be different,

Ah I see. Thanks. Btw, did you give a thought to the variant I suggested? i.e. $X_{n}$ are independent and follows $\frac{1}{n}\delta_{n}+(1-\frac{1}{n})\delta_{0}$ distribution.

@Mr.GandalfSauron: if $\mathbb{P}(X_n=n)=1/n$, consider the sequence $m_k=2^k$. For $n$ between $m_k$ and $m_{k+1}$, you have $2^k$ variables each of which has the probability of being positive of order $2^{-k}$, hence the total number of them not being zero is roughly $Poisson(1)$, and each has a value around $2^k$. So the limit will have the distribution something like $\xi_0+\xi_1/2+\xi_2/2^2+\dots$ where $\xi_i$ are iid Poisson. However, I think there is no a.s. convergence here (like in the CLT).
This is just a sketch argument though....

@Mr.GandalfSauron using the moment generating function, one can show that in your case $Y_n$ converges to $\mathcal{N}(0,1/2)$ in distribution.

I see Wolf. I don't know why but a simple way out was eluding me. Thanks

By the Borel-Cantelli's lemma for independent variables we have that events $B_j:=\{X_j \ge 2^j\}$ with probability 1 happen infinitely many times. Therefore, $\lim \sup\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n} \ge \lim \sup\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{n} = \infty$. Therefore, $Y_n$ diverges a.s.

You also need $\liminf$...
